# Keyboard issue in iOS8 with message "Can't find keyplane that supports type 4 ..."?

Tags: ios, xcode, keyboard

Few days ago I upgraded my **xCode** to version 6. Today I noticed that my software keyboard is not showing in simulator when I try to edit text field. The field is configured with ***Num pad*** keyboard. I also noticed that in the log there is an error *"Can't find keyplane that supports type 4 for keyboard iPhone-Portrait-NumberPad; using 3876877096_Portrait_iPhone-Simple-Pad_Default"*.

I investigate and find that I have to turn off *"Connect hardware keyboard"*. The keyboard is visible, but the message is still present in the log.

How to fix this?